# Populate an interface property with values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface which I want to be populated automatically with some default data when I assign variables to it. The interface is saved in a module and I want to use it on other modules. How do I assign data to interface properties ?

```js
export interface NameAge {
  valueList : Array<{ 'Name', 'Age' }>;
}
```

So I create let's say some variables in multiple modules that implement this interface.
How do I assign some default value to the **NameAge** property. I can do it with a class containing **listUsers** as **public static** property but can't replace interface with class. Also I want the interface and the *listUsers* array of objects to be in the same module so I when I import the module, I get both the interface and listUsers with the default data already populated. Thanks :))

Comment: interfaces are not available at runtime. They are meant to describe a contract not to allow you to set default values. You could use a class for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces will not allow you to do that.

However you can do it with classes.

```js
class NameAge {
    public valueList: Array<{ 'Name', 'Age' }> = [{
        'Name': 'J',
        'Age': 'ABC'
    }];
}


class NameAgeChild extends NameAge {
    public child: boolean

    public adults() {
        return this.valueList.filter(v => v.Age >= 18);
    }
}
```

This however makes sense only if you need a class for this value (code + behaviour together) in your app.

If not, just make a constant with the your values and use it when you create new instances.

Comment: Awesome!! I was thinking the same :) Is it a good practice to add even the type definition to the object properties (ie. valueList: Array<{'Name': string; 'Age': boolean}> or just say valueList: NameAge. Thanks again :)

Comment: well.. if you don't add the typing yourself the compiler will most likely assume it will be **any** like the type of the Name and Age properties are in your example. You should type those as well.